# HangFire on .NET framework 4.6 doesn't work with SQL Server 2017 instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2017, .net-4.6.1, hangfire-sql

I tried to use HangFire with SQL Server 2017 but it doesn't work.

The error encountered is

> Hangfire.BackgroundJobClientException: 'background job creation failed'

The same setting works with SQL Server 2016.

Even with the compatibility Level setting, can not create the database

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
              .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
```

Does someone have the same problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Are your user permissions identical between the two instances?  What is the inner exception as that will provide way more detail into what may be causing the job creation to fail.

Comment: yes, Same persmissions :                                                                   InnerException {"Incorrect syntax near ','."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Comment: What version of hangfire are you using?

Comment: I am using v1.7.6